# mapping shared POCO to oData controllers with plural names

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2, simple.odata

I have an ODataController called `LoggerEntriesController` that returns a POCO type of `WebModels.LoggerEntry`.  The POCO is in an external library that is shared between the client and sever.

I register the `EntitySet` like this:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<WebModels.LoggerEntry>("LoggerEntries");
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

In my `/api` metadata I see:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:3177/api/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"LoggerEntries","kind":"EntitySet","url":"LoggerEntries"
    },{
      "name":"LoggerEntry","kind":"EntitySet","url":"LoggerEntry"
    }
  ]
}
```

This causes issues with Simple.Odata.Client being unable to resolve LoggerEntry to the /api/LoggerEntries url and I get a 404 when making strongly typed calls like:

```
await this.Client
    .For<LoggerEntry>()
    .Set(new LoggerEntry()
    {
        Title = title,
        Message = message,
    })
    .InsertEntryAsync();
```

This leads me to believe that the `/api` metadata should be like:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:3177/api/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"LoggerEntry","kind":"EntitySet","url":"LoggerEntries"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or what I need to do to get the latter metadata result from the ODataConventionModelBuilder.

Comment: In the service doc (aka metadata), the `name` property should actually be `LoggerEntries`, since that is the name you gave the entity set in your configuration. What happens if you replace `For<LoggerEntry>()` with `For("LoggerEntries")` in your client code?

Comment: I think that is simply changing strongly from the strongly typed client method. 

In the metadata, if the name and the URL are both plural, wouldn't the client then assume the type to be plural also?  I am of the understanding that this metadata mapping is also how the client knows the name of the type as singular, and the collection as plural. Admittedly I have no reference to back up that last one.

Comment: @lencharest, to clarify the client call is the part that needs to stay the same to keep it strongly typed using the specific shared type.

Comment: I was simply asking you to do an experiment to help isolate the problem.

Comment: To be clear, there are potentially 2 problems you are facing. 1) If you are only configuring 1 entity set in the service, then your service document should have only 1 entry, and it should be named `LoggerEntries`. 2) Does Simple.OData.Client know it is supposed to pluralize the type name `LoggerEntry` when creating the request URI?

Comment: ah, I understand, thus not posting it as an answer :)  I will try that.

Comment: Your 1) is correct.  I wonder if anyone can speak to the metadata question.  Maybe I will submit another question about that specifically about the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you have both LoggerEntries and LoggerEntry entity sets in your service metadata, and Simple.OData.Client picks the first it one that satisfies its rules (which are quite simple reflecting the library name - it accepts anything that matches the name either in plural or singular form).

The version 5 of S.O.D will have more strict control over naming conventions, but even using this version I believe you should be able to get around the problem by specifying explicitly the entity set name, i.e.

```
await this.Client
    .For<LoggerEntry>("LoggerEntries")
    .Set(new LoggerEntry()
    {
        Title = title,
        Message = message,
    })
    .InsertEntryAsync();
```

Comment: Does the current version of Simple.OData.Client retrieve and parse the service document?

Comment: Yes it does. But only once, it caches the metadata document.

Comment: By my reading of the code (and I admit I have not yet actually used S.O.D), it is retrieving the _metadata_ document (e.g., `http://host/$metadata`) but not the _service_ document (e.g., `http://host/`, the doc at the service base URI).

Comment: Oh yes I meant service metadata document, the one that's specified by OData protocol. Not sure what other document you mean in the context of OData communication.

Comment: The JSON posted by @DrydenMaker is a [service document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940626), which is part of the OData [service model](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398203).

Comment: It uses standard ODataLib API to retrieve service metadata document.

Comment: This answer allows me to hit the endpoint properly, but I am still not sure if the metadata is correct.